# how to ignore api or property in swagger codegen

Tags: swagger-codegen

We need the possibility to add some annotation/extension, on API level and on parameter level, which marks the swagger to ignore it and not generate it (not to generate in the java outputs).
Any ideas how can it done?

```
paths:
  /productOffering:
    get:
      galit-ignore:
      tags:
      - "ProductOffering"
      description: |
        This service retrieves product offering details .
      operationId: "getProductOfferingsDetails"
      parameters:
      - name: "productOfferingId"
        in: "query"….
```

I want that the swagger won't generate the productOffering.

Thanks, Galit

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#selective-generation

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `<generateApis>false</generateApis>` in your configuration for code-gen. Take a look at the snippet below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger-codegen-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>codegen</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                <!-- other config here -->
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think is to preprocess the OpenAPI/Swagger spec using a parser such as [Swagger Parser](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser) and remove those operations, properties before passing it to Swagger Codegen.